# Palindrome Partitioning problem in O(N^2) time

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, palindrome

Problem description:

> Given a string s, partition s such that every substring of the partition is a palindrome. Return the minimum cuts needed for a palindrome partitioning of s.

[Problem link](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning-ii/)

Though I was able to code O(N^3) [solution](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/322711850/) but facing problem in O(N^2) optimization

This is the optimized [solution explanation](https://leetcode.com/problems/palindrome-partitioning-ii/discuss/42213/Easiest-Java-DP-Solution-(97.36))

In the very first line "cut[i] is the minimum of cut[j - 1] + 1 (j <= i), if [j, i] is palindrome"

Why is this the case?
Formal proof is not essential, intuition will also do.

Comment: I'm sure leetcode has a question / answer forum.  It seems someone has directed a lot of the online judge website traffic here.

Comment: somebody has asked this question in the comments on leetcode, but the answer is not satifactory and has been voted down

Answer (score 1):

If `S[j..i]` is a palindrome, that section (from `j` to `i`) accounts for the `ith` valid cut (and the `+ 1` in the formula). Since we have fixed a valid `ith` cut for this iteration, all we need to do is find the best overall minimal cut for the preceding part of the string. In a dynamic program, each iteration typically stores the overall cumulative best, which means we don't need to look farther back than `j-1`, but we have multiple `j`s to try.

Comment: Why are we evaluating only when S[j...i] is a palindrome, why not otherwise? I think we should evalute for all positions of j and take the minimum. Am i wrong?

Comment: @Light71192 that's exactly what we're doing. Hence `for(int j = 0; j <= i; j++)` in the code.

Comment: @Light71192 but it seems to me that you asked about the logic behind each evaluation in that iteration.

Answer (score 1):

We are basically trying to get the minimum cuts required for the substring[0 to i] to make the partitions palindromic. Hence, we are checking if the substring[j+1, i-1] is a palindrome. If that is a palindrome we are trying to update it by considering the substring [j+1, i-1](1 extra cut between j-1 and j positions) + c[j](which is the minimum cuts required for substring[0, j]).

Basically, the difference between the O(n^3) approach and the O(n^2) approach is the dimensions we use for the dp matrix.

Since we have already computed the minimum cut values from the start for each c[i] = minimum cuts of substring[0,i], the jth loop's(2nd loop) function is to check where to partition. We only partition the substring[0 to i] into two parts every time we run the second loop because the minimum cuts required for the former string is already calculated and the latter is already a palindrome. We do this until i = n-1 so the min cuts are calculated for substring[1 to n-1].

I highly recommend you to please check with multiple cases and traverse the loops. Trust me! that would be more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

this is dp solution of mine dp[i][j] rep partitioning required if we check the string from index i to j
my base case is dp[i][i]  = 0 as string of single character is itself palindrome
transition i am taking dp[i][j]=0 if string is palindrome
and if not dp[i][j]=min(dp[i][p]+dp[p+1][j]+1) where p represents places of partion for the length i to j basically p contais all points of possible partion in the range i to j

```
// User function Template for C++

class Solution{
public:
bool ispal(string s,int l,int r)
    {
        for(int i=l;i<=r;i++)
        {
            if(s[i]!=s[r])return false;
            r--;
        }
        return true;
    }
    int palindromicPartition(string str)
    {
        int n=str.length();
        int dp[n][n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            dp[i][i]=0;
            
        }
       
       for(int len=1;len<=n;len++)
       {
           for(int start=0;start+len<=n;start++)
           {
               if(ispal(str,start,start+len-1))dp[start][start+len-1]=0;
               else
               {  dp[start][start+len-1]=100000000;
                   for(int p=start;p<start+len-1;p++)
                   {
                       dp[start][start+len-1]=min(dp[start][start+len-1],dp[start][p]+dp[p+1][start+len-1]+1);
                   }
               }
           }
       }
    
       return dp[0][n-1];
    }
};
```